# How to make an input filter

Tags: zend-framework

Am watching a tutorila by Bo Andersen make on zend framework but in the middle of the tutorial he did not show as how to make the AddPost.php inside the input filter directory so if any one did it please show me the code. Thank you!!

Comment: Could you show us some of your code so that we can help you ? SO is here to help you solve a problem, not doing it for you. So please, show us what you've tried.

Comment: ok here is the code